# Compute average from grouped data-frames with different number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of comma separated grouped dataframes as below with columns **id_** and **val**. The dataframes can have varying number of rows.

```
df=
[id_  val
2       5
2       15,          
id_  val
2       5
3      25
2       4
3      20,          
id_  val
2      10
3      10]
```

I want to iterate through each dataframe in the list and pass the two column values to a function `computeAverage(df.id_,df.val)`, which first multiples the **id_** column and **val** column of each dataframe, then adds up the multipled values and returns the average from each dataframe.

i.e, `(2*5 + 2*15)/df.shape[0], (2*5 + 3*25 + 2*4 + 3* 20) /df.shape[0], and (2*10 + 3*10)/df.shape[0]`

This is what I have tried so far, but it fails to iterate through all rows of each dataframe.

```
def get_df(df):

    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        id_ = df[i]['id_']
        val = df[i]['val']

def computeAverage(df.id_,df.val):

    sum_ = 0
    multiply = df.id_ * df.val
    sum_ += multiply
    avg = sum_ / df[i].shape[0]
    return avg
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output in the form you expect ( a dataframe, a Series, a list?)

Comment: The output must be a list of averages for each dataframe i.e., 3 averages for the 3 dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the function:

```
In [25]: def computeAverage(df, Id, val):
    ...:     result = df[Id].mul(df[val])
    ...:     result = result.mean()
    ...:     return result
```

Run a list comprehension, combining it with the `pipe` function:

```
In [28]: [frame.pipe(computeAverage, 'id_', 'val') for frame in df]
Out[28]: [20.0, 38.25, 25.0]
```

Comment: I have edited my question and would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve it

Comment: Kindly post it as a new question and tag me. Makes it easier for folks to contribute. The edited question looks different from the original